# Android, MVC, who should announce error

Tags: android, model-view-controller

I have a form, ask user to input, then check if all required field are filled, then save the data from the form. 
So, in MVC, **the Controller** (I have a separate controller class, not using Fragment or Activity as controller) will check the form's input, and if everything is good, the model is created and passed down to data layer. Otherwise, I want to set the color of the problematic text view to red, also throw  a toast. Now I have the options:

- return an `int` or enum result so the Fragment will know which field is troubling, and the Fragment will handle the announcement
- let the controller handle the announcement, which means I have to pass the Context into the **Controller**.

In terms of good architecture, which way is cleaner? Or do you have even a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment`s are view controllers, they are responsible for creating the UI, so I would implement all this validation logic inside a `Fragment` itself. All this field validation is directly related to the UI because you are going to highlight fields with errors.

If you want to go with a separate controller which is not a `Fragment`, it would be better to return an `int` value to the `Fragment` and let it handle the UI changes.

It's not a good idea to move UI logic somewhere out of the `Fragment` or `Activity` because why do you need a `Fragment` then? It will just delegate UI callbacks to your controller? It sounds like unnecessary complications.

The only case where I would move UI logic out of the `Fragment` or `Activity` is when the code should be shared across multiple UI components. So in this case it makes sense because you can avoid code duplication.

Comment: I normally use fragment logic to handle other view component (like load, replace child fragment), set adapter to listview, .etc. which really need to be on fragment. With form validation, I feel it shouldn't be coupled to a fragment, like fragment has to handle too many things. Anyway, I think your answer makes sense.

Comment: well, you can implement that controller, I don't think there would be any significant difference between your solution and mine. It's a matter of taste.. both solutions are flexible, you can extend the functionality if you need. So probably just peek the one you like most. I personally don't like such architecture but I don't see any really bad things it can cause.